# Travelling into UK with a wooden chopping board?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, england

Looking at purchasing some painted wooden chopping boards as gifts for family.  Travelling from Australia to the UK.  Anyone know if there is an issue with this?

Comment: What would be the total value and do you have the receipts that you could present to customs?

Comment: An FYI for anyone surprised by this question: Australia (and some other South Pacific nations e.g. New Zealand) have strict rules designed to prevent ecologically-damaging outbreaks of non-native flora or fauna, and [wooden items generally need to be declared and inspected](https://www.agriculture.gov.au/biosecurity-trade/import/goods/timber/personal_imports_of_timber_and_wooden_related_articles) for things like boreholes that might indicate live non-native insects etc. Such rules are less strict in "old world" countries whose ecosystems already adapted to centuries of intercontinental trade.

Comment: I very much doubt our UK Customs care about wooden chopping boards, as such… and don't you think the very idea is suspicious enough to invite investigation?

'Everyone knows' travelling from Australia to the UK, the gifts you bring are Aussie things such as most obviously boomerangs or didgeridoos.

Why you might trek half-way round the world to give a gift of something your people could buy in many a local store makes the whole idea deeply suspicious.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I brought a Huon pine rolling pin back from Tasmania. Can't get that wood in the USA. The painting *on* the boards could be Australia-specific, too; there's nothing inherently suspicious about a wood-based souvenir. (My importation of kangaroo scrotum leather coin pouches raised an eyebrow, though.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Good for you. I'm sorry I have no idea what a Huon pine rolling pin might be and to Jo Average customs officer, how might it differ from a High Street rolling pin?  

The painting on the boards could be Australia-specific only if it could be shown that shops in the destination country could not copy/duplicate/fake it.

If you were a competent customs officer, everything about a wooden souvenir that did not demonstrate singular and special origin would be inherently suspicious 

D'you think leather coin pouches would have raised  eyebrows had you not identified the source?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "If you were a competent customs officer, everything about a wooden souvenir that did not demonstrate singular and special origin would be inherently suspicious" No, if you're a competent customs officer, you're focusing on actual violations of customs regulations. Not "you could've bought one of these here" paranoia.

Comment: @ceejayoz If simple logic doesn't work for you, try watching more day-time TV, where every day you can see relevant examples.

FYI focusing on violations is possible only after something or other has raised clues, doubts or suspicions. 

'you could've bought those here' is a strong clue that something is odd. 

If you can't see that, any smuggler might be glad to have you as a customs officer and any government, glad not to.

Comment: "FYI focusing on violations is possible only after something or other has raised clues, doubts or suspicions." Sure; the point is "I bought a cutting board as a gift" isn't going to. (I've also traveled internationally enough times with gifts to be pretty comfortable with this fact, and tend to rank that higher than day-time TV as evidence.)

Answer (score 10):

Travellers can bring non-alcohol and tobacco goods into the UK worth up to £390 (e.g. perfume and electrical goods) without paying duty and/or tax in the UK. The goods must be for your own use or as gifts. Anything over this amount must be declared.

Source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/946504/6.7005__SE_CUS_v3.pdf

There are some restrictions on importing plants and plant products. Whether these apply to your intended gifts will likely depend eg on the type of wood, how it has been processed/packaged etc. It’s not easy to negotiate and understand the various sources of information; I would recommend:

- if in doubt, *declare the items*
- don’t bring non commercially packaged items

Example (there may be others): https://www.gov.uk/guidance/import-wood-wood-products-or-bark

Comment: The online versions can be found here: applies also to **Gifts** [Bringing goods into the UK for personal use: Overview - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-goods-into-uk-personal-use) and the **£390** limit [Bringing goods into the UK for personal use: Arriving in Great Britain - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-goods-into-uk-personal-use/arriving-in-Great-Britain)

Comment: "If in doubt, declare it" ? YMMV: the few times I did declare something it's been always a huge pain. I've never had a problem with not declaring.

Comment: @Hilmar While not-declaring has the chance of saving you a bit of (short term) administrative hassle, it can have a non-zero probability of getting you into a load of legal hassle. If you think the customs agent was unsympathetic to you declaring something you didn't need to, think of how much more unsympathetic they would be if they discovered you deliberately omitted declaring something you should have.

Comment: @Hilmar: LOL. Being caught by the police for a crime has always been a huge pain. I've never had a problem when not being caught.

Comment: @Hilmar In New Zealand (a different country) I have often found that declaring what you have on you sometimes gets you directed past the long "nothing to declare - we don't believe you" X-ray line

Answer (score 9):

The UK has no restrictions on the importation of wood, unlike Australia.

So you will have to look at the total value of the gifts, same as all other items you bring into the UK intended to leave behind.

Comment: What makes you think so? Wood is explicitely mentioned here: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/importing-plants-fruit-vegetables-or-plant-material-to-the-uk

Comment: The *living part of a plant* (including a 'Plant product', unprocessed or having undergone simple preparation) is restricted both in the UK and EU.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Even the most enthusiastic Customs officer would likely struggle to call a wooden chopping board made from treated wood a "living part of a plant".

Comment: @lambshaanxy I agree. That why I quoted the ***living** part of a plant* to make that clear.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The page I am linking to concerns 'plants' (living plants) *and* 'plant products', under which, and I repeat myself, 'wood' is explicitely mentioned: *‘Plant product’ means products of plant origin, unprocessed or having undergone simple preparation, in so far as these are not plants, including wood and bark.* I don't see why wooden chopping boards should not be covered by that description. The purpose of the restriction is to prevent import of plant pests and diseases and a wooden chopping board could of course be a risk.

Comment: @lambshaanxy The restricted 'plant products' described on the page I am linking to do of course have nothing to do with living plants. 'Wood' is explicitely mentioned as a regulated plant product.

Comment: Note: it is about a unprocessed (or with little processes) wood (which can contain diseases and bugs, and it is easy to miss them). In any case, it is simpler to ask border protection (the above link has also a contact email).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, the proper clasification is most likely [Commodity code 4419900000: Tableware and kitchenware, of wood, Other - UK Integrated Online Tariff - GOV.UK](https://check-how-to-import-export-goods.service.gov.uk/import/check-licences-certificates-and-other-restrictions?commodity=4419900000&destinationCountry=GB&goodsIntent=bringGoodsToSell&importDateDay=26&importDateMonth=1&importDateYear=2023&importDeclarations=yes&importOrigin=&originCountry=AU&tradeType=import&userTypeTrader=true) ; chopping boards are not a organic produce.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, saying that you can not take wood into the UK is like saying you can not take medication into the UK. There are some (rare) exceptions which are not allowed but for the most you can just bring it in. I would not suggest to take green wood (just cut down trees) but a finished wooden item is usually not a problem anywhere in Europe or North America.

Comment: It also depends on the type of wood. Any wood coming from protected plant species would almost certainly raise very serious eyebrows, and could lead to confiscation, fines, or worse. Not a problem with a piece of oak, but say koa (no a NZ species, it only grows on some islands in the Hawaiian chain) need a special permit.

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure about Australia, but almost everywhere else in the world I have been, it is not uncommon that products made of more or less fresh wood are sold, often made by local craftsmen and directly marketed at tourists. Your last claim ("finished wooden item is usually not a problem ...") is simply wrong. In the EU, there are for example relatively strict restrictions for import of many types of wood from certain origins to prevent the spread of the Asian long-horned beetle. These restrictions even apply to packaging material made of wood.

Comment: @Willeke The question is about a cutting board...those are often unprocessed, because a lot of wood processing (pressure treating, resin stabilizing, etc.) is not necessarily food safe, or sometimes even just the perception that such processes may not be food safe. (And obviously things like pesticide are right out...)